# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^5{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}\ d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find the mass of a spherical object with a given density function, and to do so I must solve this integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^5{\theta}\cos^2{\theta}\ d\theta,$$

but no matter which method I choose (integration by parts, substitution, etc) I can't for the life of my figure out the anti-derivative.

Comment: $\sin^5\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin\theta (1-\cos^2\theta)^2\cos^2\theta$. Let $u=\cos\theta$.

Comment: Who cares about the anti-derivative? The problem doesn't ask for one.

Comment: See also [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\cos\theta$ then $dx=-\sin\theta d\theta$ hence

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^5\theta\cos^2\theta d\theta=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^2x^2dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can thank you. I didn't think of using trigonometric identities, silly me.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Are you sure there shouldnt be a $-$ sign there? Since $x=\cos\theta$, then $dx=-\sin\theta d\theta$

Comment: By this sign we interchange the limits of the integral:
$$-\int_1^{-1}=\int_{-1}^1$$

Comment: Ah yes that is true.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach:**

Consider [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$
\text{B}(x,y)=2\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}(\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}\ d\theta=\frac{\Gamma(x)\cdot\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}.
$$
Rewrite
$$
\int_0^{\large\pi}\sin^5\theta\cos^2\theta\ d\theta=2\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\sin^5\theta\cos^2\theta\ d\theta,
$$
then
$$
\int_0^{\large\pi}\sin^5\theta\cos^2\theta\ d\theta=\frac{\Gamma\left(3\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\dfrac32\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac92\right)}=\frac{2!\cdot\Gamma\left(\dfrac32\right)}{\dfrac72\cdot\dfrac52\cdot\dfrac32\cdot\Gamma\left(\dfrac32\right)}=\large\color{blue}{\frac{16}{105}},
$$
where $\Gamma(n+1)=n\cdot\Gamma(n)$.